# Three questions on WSO2 system architecture

Tags: wso2

This is more an architectural post than anything else and I apologise for asking several questions. I'm trying to fully understand how I can successfully use WSO2.

I'm trying to visualise the architecture for my servers. I think I need an ESB, API Manager, Application Server, an Identity Server and probably a BAM.

1) I assume that the binaries for each of these all include their own registry. Should I (can I?) run a shared Governance Registry server with its own database (PGSQL).

2) Do all of these servers inter-connect (where required) using the ESB?

3) Is there anything else these servers need to share? I assume I'll need to cluster Tomcat sessions somehow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answers below.

1) For this there are several ways you can do it. It is fine to use local registries for each server and you can use the shared one if needed. (That depends on the usecase). Please refer this post.
http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances

2) Yes.You can use ESB as a integration layer for these servers.

I hope following will be a great resource for your questions.

http://wso2.com/blogs/architecture/